# Geolocation feature: strictly "location" metadata?

Tags: geolocation, fiware-orion

Orion geolocation feature involves an attribute, which value represents WGS84 coordinates and an associated metadata:

`{"name":"location","value":"WGS84","type":"string"}`

If the attribute itself keeps its value to WGS84 coordinates, could the metadata be modified (e.g. change its name to `localización` or its type to `coordinates`) and keep the feature working? or this metadata is somehow hard coded and MUST be specified in that way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fields of the metadata used to "mark" the attribute which means entity location work as follow:

- The `name` cannot be freely chosen, it is fixed to `location`.
- The `type` is not taken into account in the current Orion version (0.19.0) so can be freely chosen. However, we recommend to use `string` (as shown in the documentation).
- The `value` cannot be freely chosen, it is fixed to `WGS84`. In the future, the set of available coordinates systems could grow but, by the moment (i.e. 0.19.0) this is the way it works.

Note the name of the attribute to which that metadata is associated can be freely chosen. The attribute name could be "location" (in this case it would match with the name of the metadata), "coordinates", or whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks fgalan. According to the different tests we've performed using Orion 0.19.0, if we choose a different value for "type" element (e.g. coordinates") Orion ignores this and automatically sets this value to "string". Can this be considered as a bug?

Comment: It seems to be a bug, although a very minor one. Added to Github issues: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/845

Comment: Note that "location" metadata as a way of specifying entity location has been deprecated since Orion 1.1 (see https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/deprecated/index.html). Please, have a look to the Geolocation section in the Orion manual to know the current ways of doing: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/geolocation/index.html